# Ensuring a high score sent from client is "real"

Tags: security, networking

I'm looking for a decent way to ensure that high scores sent from clients are, in fact, real (for use in a global high score board), to prevent users from sending fake scores.

The method doesn't need to be super-duper-secure, but some level of security would be nice.

I was thinking something like so:

`www.website.com/submitbest.php?player=bob&score=500&digest=xxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Where I send the player name and score along with a salted hash of the whole string. Then, I can check on the server if the hash is what it should be.

Is this decent enough? Are there simpler ways that I'm overlooking?

Comment: The only secure way is to handle all the scoring on the server.

Comment: @Mike Scoring on server is unlikely to be a good solution if the game is meant to be played offline, like most mobile games.

Comment: Yes, I should add, this is for an Android game.

Comment: Yea, encrypting the result with a shared key, or using a validation hash are both fine approaches.  It would take someone reverse engineering your code to find the key, unless your game is Angry Birds no one is gonna care enough.

Comment: You could keep a replayable log of every in-game action, send it to the server, and replay it. =) (of couse, someone could reverse engineer your replay format, but it might increase the effort level!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this decent enough? Are there simpler ways that I'm overlooking?

It's up to you to decide if it's "decent" enough. As far as security is concerned, it's trivial for a anyone to produce the required hash and send hashed highscores to the server. So the real work is in discovering the algorithm + challenge used, which will probably be embedded in the code, thus discoverable.

The gist of the matter is that you're checking on the server whether the user knows the hashing algorithm, there's no way to actually check if the message is genuine.